# Rowspan in the view (mvc4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using MVC 4 with the Entity Framework. I've the following problem.

My raw data in the view is displaying in that way:

```
id | name| email| roles| modules
1|name1| email1| role1| module1
1| name1| email1| role2| module1
1| name1| email1|role3| module1
```

What I need to do is rowspan like this

```
id | name| email| roles| modules
1|name1| email1| role1, role2, role3| module1
```

I believe that it's better to make it in the controller than in the view. If so, how to do that with the Linq or simple list?

Comment: That is not rowspan (which is an HTML construct), that is grouping (which is an SQL construct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is `GroupBy`:-

```
IEnumerable<TestForms.Models.v_HmsUnacceptedForms> result = data.GroupBy(x => x.id)
                 .ToList()   //To force run projection in memory.
                 .Select(x => 
               {
                     var firstRecord = x.FirstOrDefault();
                     return new TestForms.Models.v_HmsUnacceptedForms
                    {
                       id = x.Key,
                       name = firstRecord != null ? firstRecord.name : String.Empty,
                       email = firstRecord != null ? firstRecord.email: String.Empty,
                       roles = String.Join(",",x.Select(z => z.roles),
                       modules = firstRecord != null ? firstRecord.modules : String.Empty
                    };
               });
```

Here, I have considered that for each id, you need the first `name,email and modules` column. if this is not the case you can group by multiple columns instead of id like `new { x.id, x.name, x.email }`.

Comment: I've problems with testing your code because I wnat to use it as a list so after: result.ToList() receive an error:
The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead. When I change to FirstOrDefault. Ivgot error Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: See my prev post. Ive changed to FirstIrDefault() but got:  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join... I thing this is not the case of no matching records.

Comment: String.Join cannot be translated to SQL.  You need to force the query to run and perform the string join on the client.  You can call `.ToList()` before your `.Select`

Comment: OK. The controller pass the code but in the view I have The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int64,TestForms.Models.v_HmsUnacceptedForms],<>f__AnonymousType4`7[System.Int64,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestForms.Models.v_HmsUnacceptedForms]'. My declaration in the view is @model IEnumerable<TestForms.Models.v_HmsUnacceptedForms>

Comment: @arth81 - Yes cz I was trying to fetch the anonymous type but your view must be expecting a strongly typed list, so instead i have used your model class `TestForms.Models.v_HmsUnacceptedForms`, but please make sure all the datatypes matches with that of what I am fetching.